# What piece is this ARC-170 Starfighter cockpit?

Tags: part-identification, star-wars

I got these with the [ARC-170 LEGO Starfighter (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20111113165601/http://starwars.lego.com/en-us/products/arc-170+starfighter%E2%84%A2/8088.aspx):

[image] 
[image]

I'd like to get more if possible. They are a part of the cockpit.

Comment: Is this from the cockpit?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes it is. Sorry, should have mentioned that in the question. *edits*

Comment: It's common for the pieces to have numbers printed on them. Try to see if the numbers are visible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That looks like [30384 Windscreen 7 x 4 x 2 Round](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=30384). In general, [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/) is a pretty decent place to browse around for parts identification. [Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/30384) is also pretty good.

BrickLink provides a comprehensive list of windscreens both [plain](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=115) and [decorated](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=579).

Comment: Ahh, experienced researcher found the brick where I just found the set

Comment: +1 for Peeron. If you know the set, you should be able to find the piece there.

Answer (score 19):

This is the [Trans-Black Windscreen 7 x 4 x 2 Round](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=30384)

Answer (score 8):

[(7259) ARC-170](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=7259-1) or [(8088) ARC-170 Starfighter](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=8088-1).

The part can be found in [these sets on Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30384&in=S) and a [cool alternative list](http://en.bricker.ru/parts/30384/).

Comment: I believe the question is asking for the specific piece, not the set.

Comment: @Rebecca - I expected that first identifying the set would help find the brick... See the last links